# Google Play Console InApp billing Warning 'com.google.android.gms.internal.gw'

Tags: android-security

Google Play Console InApp billing Warning

I updated google InApp billing AIDL file and IAP Helper but Warning does not disappear anymore,

before google play service version 5089000
after google play service version 6171000

ERROR 
- com.google.android.gms.internal.gw

What should I do?

Comment: Can you give more detail?
- where does the warning appear? In the logcat? In the gradle build? In the Play console at upload?
- When does it occur? When running in an emulator? On your device? In a customer device?
- Exactly what version of Google Play services are you using? Can you show your gradle file?
- Can you show your source code where you call Google Play services?

Comment: maybe, I check that is different environment Between Eclipse and Android Studio. because billing API source is equal